# putExtra doesn't work with textinputedittext

Tags: android

I have a class:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button5;
    TextInputEditText textoinput;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addpriority);

        textoinput = findViewById(R.id.texto);
        String dados = textoinput.getText().toString();


        button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);

        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivityMenu.class);
                intent.putExtra("chave", dados);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The putExtra doesn't read the textinputedittext. If I replace from dados to "teste", it works.

Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to run it in the onclick. Doing it in the beginning reads it then, it doesn't cause it to always update with new data.

Answer (score 0):

The `onCreate` method is called each time the Activity is built so in your case before you intend to another Activity it won't run again that means that with this line of code

```
String dados=textoinput.getText().toString();
```

You will only get the text from the edit text once which is when the main activity has been created any text after that won't be put in the dados variable mean while the listener is a method which is called every time you click on the button so you initialize it once but run multiple time that's why in order to get the value of the current text you need to put it in the click listener to be called every time the button is clicked so your code will be like:

```
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
    String dados = textoinput.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivityMenu.class);
    intent.putExtra("chave", dados);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Consider reading about Android Application activity life cycle

Answer (score 0):

put this line `String dados = textoinput.getText().toString();`
into your onclick before intent i.e.,

```
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String dados = textoinput.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivityMenu.class);
                intent.putExtra("chave", dados);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

It will work!!